# Mathematical modelling of a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving, mathematical-modeling

I wonder if how you represent this scenario.
**It has been determined that 2400 clocks would be sold if the wholesale price is 3.20 dollars. However, if the price were reduced to 2.4 dollars, there would be 4800 clocks sold. Find a mathematical model expressing the wholesale price as a function of the number of clocks sold.** First, I assumed that the relationship is linear. But I couldn't seem to find a way to represent them as a function.

Comment: Number_sold = price_per_clock(change_in_sales_number_per_unit_price) + fixed_cost

Comment: For a linear function, you just need to find the equation of the line passing through the points $(3.2, 2400)$ and $(2.4, 4800)$

Comment: I think it should be (2400, 3.2) and (4800, 2.4) since the wholesale price is a function of the number of clocks sold. Please enlighten me with your idea.

Answer (score 0):

I considered @saulspatz's comment and I have come to the realization that I only have to find an equation of the line containing two points. It should be noted that the problem was asking for the mathematical model where the price is a function of the number of clocks sold. Thus, we have the ordered pairs (2400, 3.2) and (4800, 2.4). Using desmos app,
[image: graph of the equation]

we have $y=-\frac{x}{3000} + 4$.